# mod rewrite - clarification

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# URL REWRITE
RewriteRule ^domain-name/?$ domain.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/registration/?$ domain-registration.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/price/?$ domain-price.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/security/?$ domain-security.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/features/?$ domain-features.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/faq/?$ domain-faq.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/provider/?$ domain-why-choose-us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/free/?$ domain-free.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/transfer/?$ domain-transfer.php [L]

# 301
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My question is, If i enter http://domain.com/domain-name/free
this is working fine. But

http://www.domain.com/domain-name/free
is goes to my original php file (free.php)

How to solve this?

---

**Problem Solved  My correct code is bellow**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# 301
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.globaliway\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://globaliway.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# URL REWRITE
RewriteRule ^domain-name/?$ domain.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/registration/?$ domain-registration.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/price/?$ domain-price.php [L]
```

Comment: please try to make clear what exactly you want to do, and in which computer language. This is incomprehensible, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your .htaccess file to fix few things, please copy/paste from here **INCLUDING** the option line `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# URL REWRITE
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^domain-name/?$ /domain.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/registration/?$ /domain-registration.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/price/?$ /domain-price.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/security/?$ /domain-security.php [L,NC]

# 301
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanx. My code follows (not working)

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# handles http redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# URL REWRITE
RewriteRule ^domain-name/?$ domain.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/registration/?$ domain-registration.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/price/?$ domain-price.php [L]
RewriteRule ^domain-name/security/?$ domain-security.php [L]

Comment: Difficult to understand from comments, would you append that in your question please?

Comment: I update my answer above, try to copy/paste that into your .htaccess file and test.

Comment: @anubhava
Thanks for your help. I have used your code, but still same issue. Kindly help me. Thanx in advance. :)

Comment: You mean it is still going to `free.php`? Would you be able to paste your web server's access log segments when you send this request from your browser.

Comment: @Joshua: If you think my answer helped you to resolve this (esp: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`) would you pls mark this answer as accepted.